# I killed sshd but it's still running?

Tags: sshd

On AIX 6100-05-01-1016 I accidentally killed the sshd. But for a suprise it still was running. Why? I did a:

```
kill PID
```

Q: ..so sshd doesn't reacts to normal kill signal? or are there any default security methods that starts an sshd if the old one get's killed?

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for certain these days, but AIX used to run `inetd`. This is a daemon that listens to various ports and starts another daemon (like `sshd` or `ftpd`) on the connection.  Check to see if `inetd` or `xinetd` is running (`ps -e | grep inet`), then look for `/etc/inet.d` or `/etc/xinet.d`.  Beyond that we would need to see what is running (`ps axo pid,cmd`).

Comment: but doesn't inetd just start the corresponding daemon when a connection is made to a given port ? i.e. would one see an `sshd` process before an actual connection is made ? (rather than just `inetd` listening on port 22 ?)

Answer (score 1):

There is a master `sshd` process that listens to incoming connections, and in addition (for recent versions of OpenSSH) there are two processes called `sshd` for each incoming SSH connection, one running as root and the other running as the logged-in user. If your OpenSSH is compiled without privilege separation (I don't know whether that's supported on AIX), there'll be a single `sshd` process per connection in addition to the main one.

You must have killed either a per-connection `sshd` or the master process, but not both. If you can still logged in over SSH, then what you killed was a per-connection process.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a "hidden" script that checks that sshd runs or not, and if it doesn't run, it starts it.

Comment: that's why I wonder whether after killing it it still has the same process id or not (see my comment above)